# How does shiny create the session$token?

Tags: r, session, shiny

Due to security reasons using the shiny [`session`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/session.html) ID (token), I would like to know, how the session token is created.

I cant´t find this in the [`docs`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/)